# Computer won't start up after deleting C:\Windows\

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a machine with Windows 7 Home Premium and it will not start up.

I basically wanted to free up some more space on the computer.... I deleted all the files... at least all the ones I could.

It won't start up, I can't go on safe mode or anything..

I'm stuck on repair mode and I already tried all the options; nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Is there any way I can restore everything to factory mode or something?  (Sorry, I have no experience with computers)

Comment: What the hell did you delete exactly?

Comment: Well, I hoverd my mouse over all sistem files (D: Windows) and deleted all the files I the sistem let me to.  The other ones needed trustedinstaller to delete, so I just clicked "ignore".

Comment: Reinstall Windows.

Comment: you don't _HAVE_ Windows Home Premium anymore. You deleted it.

Answer (score 6):

You have deleted files needed for Windows to run.  The only thing you can do is to reinstall Windows.  There are 3 ways you can do it.

1. If you have a recovery disk use that
2. If you know how to get to the system recovery part of your computer setup by the manufacturer you could use that
3. If you can't do either of these you need to go and buy a copy of Windows on CD, insert the CD and turn your computer off and back on again to start the installation process.

Comment: Reinstall or do a repair install.....

Comment: Could try a repair install but due to the extent of the files deleted you are more likely to need a reinstall.

Comment: There is not "repairing" Windows if you delete system files like the author did.